# QuickFix C++: how to continue reading in market data while another function is running?

Tags: c++, algorithmic-trading, quickfix, fix-protocol

**Goal:**

To continue printing out `market data` messages coming from a server, whilst another function containing a `while` loop listens for an input from another non-market data information source. Effectively, the function that listens for `market data` should always run regardless of what other functions are running.

**Details:**

The program below successfully sends a `market data request` message to the server. `Market data` messages containing trade information such as `bids` and `asks` is then continually printed, as required. Another function is then called which listens out for some input from an informational source using a `while` loop.

The function that detects when there is a new `market data` message is `Application::onMessage(const FIX44::MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh& mdMessage, const FIX::SessionID& session)`.

**Problem:**

When the second function that `listens` for some input is called, the stream of market data messages printed to the terminal is stopped until an input has been received, so it seems there is some `blocking` behaviour.

**Simplified program:**

```
#include "Application.h"
#include "quickfix/Session.h"

#include <iostream>

static bool listeningToMarketData = false;
static bool requestMadeAlready = false;

// Output when logged on
void Application::onLogon( const FIX::SessionID& sessionID ) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Logon - " << sessionID << std::endl;
}

// Output when logged out
void Application::onLogout( const FIX::SessionID& sessionID ) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Logout - " << sessionID << std::endl;
}

// Admin output sending from client
void Application::toAdmin( FIX::Message& message, const FIX::SessionID& sessionID) {

    // Set logon msg Username/Password
    if (FIX::MsgType_Logon == message.getHeader().getField(FIX::FIELD::MsgType))
    {
        message.getHeader().setField(FIX::Username("XXXXX"));
        message.getHeader().setField(FIX::Password("XXXXX"));
    }
}

// Output coming from server
void Application::fromApp( const FIX::Message& message, const FIX::SessionID& sessionID )
throw( FIX::FieldNotFound, FIX::IncorrectDataFormat, FIX::IncorrectTagValue, FIX::UnsupportedMessageType ) {
    crack( message, sessionID );
    std::cout << std::endl << "INCOMING: " << message << std::endl;
}

// Output sending from this client
void Application::toApp( FIX::Message& message, const FIX::SessionID& sessionID )
throw( FIX::DoNotSend ) {
    try {
        FIX::PossDupFlag possDupFlag;
        message.getHeader().getField( possDupFlag );
        if ( possDupFlag ) throw FIX::DoNotSend();
    }
    catch ( FIX::FieldNotFound& ) {}

    std::cout << std::endl << "OUTGOING: " << message << std::endl;
}

// Function handling market data
void Application::onMessage(const FIX44::MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh& mdMessage, const FIX::SessionID& session) {

    static bool isFirstMdMessage = true;
    listeningToMarketData = true;
}

void listenToMarketData() {
        FIX44::MarketDataRequest marketDataRequest(
                              FIX::MDReqID("ABC1"),
                              FIX::SubscriptionRequestType('1'),
                              FIX::MarketDepth(1));

        marketDataRequest.set( FIX::MDUpdateType(0) );
        marketDataRequest.set( FIX::NoMDEntryTypes(2) );
        marketDataRequest.set( FIX::NoRelatedSym(1) );

        FIX44::MarketDataRequest::NoRelatedSym noRelatedSym;
        FIX44::MarketDataRequest::NoMDEntryTypes noMDEntryTypes1;
        FIX44::MarketDataRequest::NoMDEntryTypes noMDEntryTypes2;

        noRelatedSym.set(FIX::SecurityIDSource("8"));
        noRelatedSym.set(FIX::SecurityID("100800"));
        noMDEntryTypes1.set( FIX::MDEntryType('0') ); // Bid
        noMDEntryTypes2.set( FIX::MDEntryType('1') ); // Offer

        marketDataRequest.addGroup( noRelatedSym );
        marketDataRequest.addGroup( noMDEntryTypes1 );
        marketDataRequest.addGroup( noMDEntryTypes2 );

        FIX::Header& mdHeader = marketDataRequest.getHeader();
        mdHeader.setField(FIX::TargetCompID("TARGET"));
        mdHeader.setField(FIX::SenderCompID("SENDER"));

        FIX::Session::sendToTarget(marketDataRequest);
}

void request() {
    requestMadeAlready = true;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "listening" << std::endl;
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}

// Run the client application
void Application::run() {
    initialiseSystem();
}

// Function initilises market data & web scraper
void Application::initialiseSystem() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            if (!listeningToMarketData) {

                listenToMarketData();
            }

            usleep(5000000);

            if (!requestMadeAlready) {
                request();
            }
        }
        catch ( std::exception & e )
        {
            std::cout << "Message Not Sent: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

**Q1.** How can the program continue to print market data whilst **simultaneously** allowing another function to listen for some other input?

Comment: _"...whilst simultaneously..."_ - Sounds like you need to use multiple threads see [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) . Don't forget synchronisation (if needed) see [Threads and data races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) .  _"...When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for your quick reply. I should have clarified in the question that I had considered `multithrading`, however, I am looking more in the context of `multithreading` using `QuickFIX C++` in terms of the syntax and methodology required.